# Ruby File Encoding Issues while Streaming

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8, ascii, rest-client

I am using RestClient to stream some files from websites and am running into encoding issues when I write to disk. I'm following this example:

```
File.open('/path/to/text/file.txt', 'w') {|f|
    block = proc { |response|
      response.read_body do |chunk|
        puts "Working on response" 
        f.write chunk
      end
    }
    RestClient::Request.new(method: :get, url: 'http://mirror.pnl.gov/releases/xenial/ubuntu-16.04-server-amd64.iso', block_response: block).execute
}
```

found as a solution in the github issues for the project: https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/issues/452. The streaming works great, so there is no problem with that.

I'm getting an assortment of byte encoding errors: `Unable to retrieve file.ext - "\\xB5\" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8"`, `"\\x8B\" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8`, `"\\xBF\" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8`. The chunk looks like this coming into the proc:

```
]???0??>?-?A
            ?11L?
                 ??Z?ؤRB?Oo????ݗ?Q?na;??ūAj?Pl??H??a
                                                    q????Q??T?N?Z?$?7gͤhD?b?9???.A?䱴.ȑE "?)ge??;-:??=??j?47m??9??Tz@???6t?^Х??`D?{cǯo8?\????R????
```

I tried running something like this: `force_encoding("ASCII-8BIT").encode('UTF-8', undef: :replace, replace: '')` but that didn't end up working either.

What's interesting is that if retrieve the file into memory, RestClient handles all the encoding automatically and I don't get these errors.

What can I do to get these encodings errors situated and stream these files properly?

Comment: Try to set [binary mode](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Open+Mode) for the file; it should help: `File.open('/tmp/foo.iso', 'wb')`.

Comment: @mudasobwa, I tried that but it didn't work. I added what the chunk looks like coming into the proc.

Comment: Wouldn’t [`IO#syswrite`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/IO.html#method-i-syswrite) help?

Comment: but it still writes the same garbage to disk

Comment: This is an ISO image, what you have expected to see? Shakespear's sonnets?

Comment: my mistake, that's just the example path the github issue had, i'll change it for clarification